# How to store an output which is by default getting printed on the console

Tags: r

I was working on this function called `residuals` in **mirt** package.

This function prints the output by default when you use `df.p = TRUE` as an argument.

What I tried:

```
library(mirt)
data(LSAT7)
LSAT7=expand.table(LSAT7)
x <- mirt(LSAT7, 1, '3PL')
ss=residuals(x, df.p=TRUE)
```

I got the output as:

```
Degrees of freedom (lower triangle) and p-values:

       Item.1 Item.2 Item.3 Item.4 Item.5
Item.1     NA  0.474  0.346  0.097  0.162
Item.2      1     NA  0.269  0.547  0.192
Item.3      1  1.000     NA  0.871  0.873
Item.4      1  1.000  1.000     NA  0.991
Item.5      1  1.000  1.000  1.000     NA
```

I want to store the this output but unfortunately I am not able to do that.

Does anyone know how to store this output without modifying the main function i.e. `residuals`

P.S. : typing  `ss` on the console prints this:

```
  Item.1 Item.2 Item.3 Item.4 Item.5
Item.1     NA -0.023 -0.030  0.052  0.044
Item.2 -0.512     NA  0.035 -0.019 -0.041
Item.3 -0.889  1.222     NA -0.005 -0.005
Item.4  2.755 -0.362 -0.026     NA  0.000
Item.5  1.952 -1.705 -0.026  0.000     NA
```

which is different than the output which is getting printed automatically.

Comment: What's the end purpose? Would `capture.output` or `sink` serve your needs?

Comment: Thank you @AnandaMahto. capture.output is giving me output as the rows. Can we not write the output in a proper matrix format?

Comment: Try `read.table(text = capture.output(print(ss)))`.

Comment: Thanks @Backlin. your code is making it look much better. But what actually I want to have the access for each element of the output (the one which is printed by default), like we access the elements of the matrix.

can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source for the residuals method for `x` you can see how this matrix is calculated and printed.

The degrees of freedom is:

```
df <- (object@K - 1) %o% (object@K - 1)
```

and the elements are:

```
df[i, j] <- pchisq(abs(res[j, i]), df = df[j, 
                      i], lower.tail = FALSE)
```

So we emulate that...

```
dfp <- function(object, res){
    df <- (object@K - 1) %o% (object@K - 1)
    diag(df)=NA
    df[upper.tri(df)] <- t(pchisq(abs(res), df = df, lower.tail = FALSE))[upper.tri(df)]

    df

}
```

and see what we get:

```
> dfp(x,ss)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,]   NA 0.4742744 0.3457484 0.09695082 0.1623715
[2,]    1        NA 0.2689685 0.54739758 0.1916354
[3,]    1 1.0000000        NA 0.87190032 0.8719003
[4,]    1 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA 1.0000000
[5,]    1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000        NA
```

There's some slight differences because `residuals` rounds the return values. Ouch.

```
> ss10=residuals(x, df.p=TRUE, digits=10)
```

prints:

```
Degrees of freedom (lower triangle) and p-values:

       Item.1    Item.2    Item.3     Item.4    Item.5
Item.1     NA 0.4744862 0.3456212 0.09694774 0.1623190
Item.2      1        NA 0.2690456 0.54726048 0.1916342
Item.3      1 1.0000000        NA 0.87124548 0.8725782
Item.4      1 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA 0.9906174
Item.5      1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000        NA
```

which my function computes:

```
> dfp(x,ss10)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
[1,]   NA 0.4744862 0.3456212 0.09694774 0.1623190
[2,]    1        NA 0.2690456 0.54726048 0.1916342
[3,]    1 1.0000000        NA 0.87124548 0.8725782
[4,]    1 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA 0.9906174
[5,]    1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000        NA
```

Better.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `getMethod("residuals", "ExploratoryClass")` you will see that if `df.p` is `TRUE` the matrix is **printed** rather than **returned**. As you don't want to modify the code, using `capture.output` can quickly get the output - but if you are willing to compromise / play with the code a little, you can write a wee function to extract the table from the `mirt` results without much trouble.

Using the `residuals` code you can derive the table and print results (not every option is included below)

```
  extractFun <- function(mirtObject) 
                {
                     res = residuals(mirtObject)
                     J <- ncol(mirtObject@Data$data)
                     df <- (mirtObject@K - 1) %o% (mirtObject@K - 1)
                     diag(df) <- NA
                     colnames(df) <- rownames(df) <- colnames(res)

                     for (i in 1:J) {
                        for (j in 1:J) {
                            if (i < j) {
                               df[i, j] <- pchisq(abs(res[j, i]), 
                                             df = df[j, i], lower.tail = FALSE)
                            }
                         }
                      }
                      df
                  }


  x <- mirt(LSAT7, 1, '3PL')
  (e <- extractFun(x))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion. Your code is also works for me. I wish I had choice for choosing two answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, here's one way that returns the output as a `data.frame`.

```
read.table(text=capture.output(ss))
```